# Datagrid vs Gridview

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Difference Between a DataGrid and a GridView in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230/the-difference-between-a-datagrid-and-a-gridview-in-asp-net)

What is main difference between Data grid and Grid View in asp.net?

Answer (score 10):

[DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) has been around since .NET 1.1 while [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) was introduced in .NET 2.0. So basically `GridView` is the successor of `DataGrid`. Here's a [nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx) on MSDN comparing both.

> Both the DataGrid and GridView controls are derived from the
>   WebControl class. Although it has a similar object model to that of
>   the DataGrid control, the GridView control also has a number of new
>   features and advantages over the DataGrid control, which include:
>   Richer design-time capabilities. Improved data source binding
>   capabilities. Automatic handling of sorting, paging, updates, and
>   deletes. Additional column types and design-time column operations. A
>   Customized pager user interface (UI) with the PagerTemplate property.
>   Differences between the GridView control and the DataGrid control
>   include: Different custom-paging support. Different event models.

Answer (score 1):

The GridView control is the successor to the DataGrid control. Like the DataGrid control, the GridView control was designed to display data in an HTML table. When bound to a data source, the DataGrid and GridView controls each display a row from a DataSource as a row in an output table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you use GridView you have a lot of options which is useful and you don't have to write code for that functions.