# What are the things which we have to change while replacing `DataGrid` to `GridView`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know that `Gridview` is a newer version, so if I have to replace `DataGrid` to`GridView`,
what are the important things which we should follow for doing so.

Comment: Replace `GridView` with `DataGrid` and correct the occurring errors. A comparison between both: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9(v=vs.100).aspx For starters, you need to change `Item...` to `Row...` e.g. `ItemDataBound` to `RowDataBound` or `e.Item` to `e.Row` or `DataGridItem` to `GridViewRow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all the properties are same in both the controls.

You need to replace the tags `TemplateColumn`,`BoundColumn` of `Datagrid` with `TemplateField`,`BoundField` for `Gridview` control.

Comment: What do you mean by tags? Please be specific.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please provide some links examples so that it could help other users. I am upvoting it for now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I would want to add the following links to `Premdeep's` answer (After I wrote this question and searched for the answer.)

1. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734161/datagrid-vs-gridview`
2. `http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/389336/What-is-the-diff-between-gridview-and-datagrid`
3. `http://forums.asp.net/t/1844852.aspx`
4. `http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/39899-Difference-between-DataGrid-GridView.aspx`
5. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb6t8gJm7Io&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW1NryGv6LxX4U4b07T4RlI`

Sorry for the duplicate question,, actually I wrote this question in hurry and got downvotes, but its no problem.

Hope my answer would help the other persons.

Comment: This should be added as a comment/suggestion not an answer :)

Comment: ok bro, I am new to this, don't know the basics of stackoverflow.
will keep in mind next time... :)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).